# Using C2DM with OAuth2 - Error Authorizing the API

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, android-c2dm

I'm trying to use C2DM with OAuth2. I've follow this article: http://www.roosmaa.net/getting-started-with-android-c2dm and another one very similar to this, but every time I try to authorize the the scope "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm" (in the https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/)
I always get the following error:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
  The redirect URI in the request: https://code.google.com/oauthplayground did not match a   registered redirect URI

  Request Detail:

  Request Details
  scope=https://code.google.com/oauthplayground
  response_type=code
  redirect_uri=https://code.google.com/oauthplayground
  access_type=offline
  approval_prompt=force
  client_id=xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Can someone give a few hints how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you actually register `https://code.google.com/oauthplayground
` in google API console?

Answer (score 1):

You must authorize **https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm**

Comment: Hi Bert. I've done that... and still no luck. Actually I have a typo in my question. I was indeed trying to authorize https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm....

Comment: Hi Valdemar, did you try to delete your API project in [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and start from scratch? Make sure you choose **Web application**, click on **more options** and replace the existing content of **Authorized Redirect URIs** with _[https://code.google.com/oauthplayground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground)_ and clear **Authorized JavaScript Origins**.